# Cross-architecture deb package generation using bloom

Tags: robotic-arm, ros-kinetic, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been building deb packages using bloom according to https://answers.ros.org/question/173804/generate-deb-from-ros-package/ and using the following commands:

```
bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --os-version xenial --ros-distro kinetic .
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

I now want to create deb packages for arm processors, but my machine is using x86_64. How do I go about cross-compiling this?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320930/cross-architecture-deb-package-generation-using-bloom/) by [femtogram](https://answers.ros.org/users/25892/femtogram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think that Debian packages are intended to be cross-compiled. I can't actually find anything via a quick peek at the New Maintainer's Guide and Debian Policy Manual but I believe that binary debs for all architectures are compiled natively or in a native environment via emulation.

The ROS build farm uses Docker containers running native environments with static qemu binaries baked in to handle the emulation.

To build using those images:

Your host system needs qemu-user-static (or you need to add the binfmt entries by hand but I don't think it's worth the trouble)

If your target environment is one that we publish images for on https://hub.docker.com/u/osrf all you need to do is run a container for your desired environment and build your package within it. If you're targeting a different environment you will need to find or build your own custom root / container image. The scripts we use to generate ours are here: https://github.com/osrf/multiarch-docker-image-generation

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2019-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0